# How to interpret the output of `nodetool status`?

Tags: cassandra

I run `nodetool status` on a Cassandra 2.0.3 instance, the output shows:

```
Datacenter: eu-west
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  154.81 KB  256     33.8%  bcfb1057-60d7-4d94-b277-a1e8c0f55cf4  1a
```

I looked for all manuals available online, but none of them explains what `UN` means.

What does the `UN` mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

U=Up
N=Normal

It's the first letter of Status followed by the first letter of State.